# How to convert a string to a tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I have created this model `model1` and I am trying to create a function which takes in different models like `model1` `model2` etc and evaluates them. In the process, I have a string called `"model1"` which I would like to convert to `model1` so I can pass the `.evaluate()` method to it. Would this be possible?

Comment: What have you tried before?

Comment: getattr(), str.replace(), list()... not a professional in python so I know none of that makes sense.

Comment: Do you want to evaluate different models which were trained before and saved to disk? Question seems a bit ambiguous, can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve a bit more?

Comment: IIUC you want to create tensorflow models named `model1` `model2` and so on? For automating the model creation?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, so I have ALREADY created ten models named from model1 to model10 and have also written a function with a for loop which creates the model names in strings, "model1", "model2" etc. Now since I have the strings, I would like to convert them to the model object - model1, model2 etc so I can use the .evaluate method on them, as "model1".evaluate() won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your previously trained models are saved to disk, you may just want to load them back into memory and evaluate as:

```
model_names = ["model1", "model2", "model3", ..., "model10"]
for model_name in model_names:
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("path/to/location/" + model_name)
    score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, ...)
```

Also, if you plan to have lots of models with sequential names, like model1, model2, ..., model_n, you can use list comprehension instead of hard coding the model names like:

```
model_names = ["model" + str(x) for x in range(1, n)]
```

Please note that these are pseudo-codes and you need to complete ... according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, the list comprehension method was exactly what I was looking for. Also, is there a way to do this if I have the models just locally saved inside my jupyter runtime and not to disk?

Comment: To create a mapping between actual models and string representations in runtime, you can use dictionaries like: models = {"model1": model1, "model2": model2, etc}. Where "model1" is a key in the models dictionary and model1 is the actual model. Then you can pass this dictionary to any number of functions as you need.